# Cannot install hexbin library R on AWS instance

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, r

I am working on a project that uses the package plotly in R.
When I tried installing plotly, hexbin (a dependency) would not compile, because it could not find the gfortran .so libraries.
I have already installed gfortran (gcc64-gfortran.x86_64), but the .so files are not installed or discoverable by `ld`. Here is the relevant part of the log:

```
$ R
> install.packages("hexbin", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/")
Installing package into ‘/home/ec2-user/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4’

...

gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib64/R/lib -L/usr/local/lib64 -o hexbin.so hbin.o hcell.o herode.o hsm.o reg.o -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath - L/usr/lib64/R/lib -lR
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgfortran
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lquadmath
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Running `ld -lgfortran --verbose` gives me this:

```
...

==================================================
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-amazon-linux/lib64/libgfortran.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-amazon-linux/lib64/libgfortran.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so failed
attempt to open /usr/lib64/libgfortran.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libgfortran.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib64/libgfortran.a failed
attempt to open /lib64/libgfortran.so failed
attempt to open /lib64/libgfortran.a failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-amazon-linux/lib/libgfortran.so failed
attempt to open /usr/x86_64-amazon-linux/lib/libgfortran.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.so failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libgfortran.a failed
attempt to open /lib/libgfortran.so failed
attempt to open /lib/libgfortran.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libgfortran.so failed 
attempt to open /usr/lib/libgfortran.a failed
ld: cannot find -lgfortran
```

`yum info gcc64-gfortran.x86_64` says that my installation of gfortran is at version 6.4.1 from amzn-main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with a standard AWS Linux instance.
I had to link both, `gfortran` and `quadmath`:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-amazon-linux/6.4.1/libgfortran.so /usr/lib/libgfortran.so
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-amazon-linux/6.4.1/libquadmath.so /usr/lib/libquadmath.so
```

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to mention libquadmath as well! +1

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. When I searched for the .so fortran file, I used the `find` command incorrectly.
I was using `find / -file gfortran.so` instead of `find / -file *gfortran*`. I simply linked it with `sudo ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-amazon-linux/6.4.1/libgfortran.so /usr/lib/libgfortran.so`, and now the link is resolved.